# Makefile structure....which one is running?

Tags: makefile

I am working at ericsson RND and analyzing their makefiles written long time back. I give a command make in a directory. That directory has a makefile that does not contain any dependency and rules etc. It just includes

-include ./Makefile.local
include make/def.mk
include congif.mk

When i run the makefile through make all, it says

all

totalclean

and then enters a directory..subdirectory of the current directory

How should i know where is it taking the dependency from. where are the rules for make all written
The makefile also contains the name of the subdirs and these subdirs are the directories where my make is running after totalclean.

Try to help please. I need to reduce the compile time of the process and i am not getting any direction.

Comment: you'll need to analyze all 3 of those included makefiles to see what's going on. it can get very complicated depending on how malicious the people who created them were.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU make you can do

```
make -pn
```

To get a list of all rules along with the file name and line number for every command.

In the output, look for the line starting with the rule name followed by a colon. One of the comments after that line will contain the filename and line number. For example:

```
#  commands to execute (from `build/build.mk', line 45):
```

Comment: Hey..thanks a ton for the answer. Can i get to know where these rules are written...i mean which makefile..i know the rules and the statements being executed but i do not know where this makefile is present. Si if you could help me in this task. I am able to see the rules

Comment: thank you!!! will get back in case of any other problem..really useful advice!!..:-
)

Answer (score 1):

To find the `all` rule, look through those three files, `Makefile.local`, `make/def.mk` and `congif.mk`. If you don't see it, you could try removing the `include` directives from the main makefile one by one, to see when "all" stops working. You can look for the `totalclean` rule the same way.

Chances are the "all" message is from the `all` rule and the "totalclean" from the `totalclean` rule (but as jcomeau_ictx points out, not every person who writes a makefile is civilized-- the messages could come from anywhere and mean anything). The fact that "totalclean" comes after "all" suggests that it is recursion, not dependency.

You haven't said what, if anything, these makefiles are actually doing. If you want to reduce the compile time by tinkering with the build process, your only hope is to prevent unnecessary compilation, which means removing unnecessary dependencies in the makefiles (and perhaps unnecessary coupling in the source code).

**EDIT:**
Ankit, you're asking for a simple formula for reducing unnecessary dependencies in a big legacy makefile system; there simply isn't one. We don't have enough information to give you detailed direction, but I'll take a shot in the dark: it looks as if your makefiles run `totalclean` every time, and rebuild from the ground up. This is almost always unnecessary. So look for the call to `totalclean` and turn it off, see if that speeds things up.

**EDIT:**
Now you have three problems: you're dealing with a big, badly designed makefile system, you're a makefile novice, and the managers are interfering.

Yes, use `make -j ...`. This might speed things up and almost certainly can't do harm.

You can try to explain to the officials that if you run `totalclean` every time, you must then recompile everything you need, and that puts a hard lower limit on build times.

You can look for unnecessary dependencies in the makefiles. There is no easy, fast way to do this, because the machine cannot know which prerequisites are really needed. If you understand the build process for a particular target, look at the rule and judge whether each prerequisite is necessary. If you're not sure, you can remove a prerequisite from a rule, make `totalclean`, make the target, then make `all`; if the target build failed, then the prerequisite was necessary, if it succeeded but the `all` build failed then the prerequisite is necessary but it should be in a different rule.

Comment: Thank you for the answer The dependencies are really large. There are a huge number of files. There are several sub directories and all have their own depend file which contains the dependencies.(found that). Now you say to reduce the compile time should i analyze all the dependencies. It will be really difficult. Can parallel execution help??.. using the -j command !!! These files were written in 1997. Basically these makefiles are converting the source code in java and c into the executable and some scripts are also used. Which direction should i look into to reduce the compile time. Present

Comment: I thought of that idea as well but the officials say we need to clean the things for sure. Is there any other method?.. should i try the -j command and test if the build gets broken and if it does, where to change the dependencies? I am a novice to makefiles so i do not have much idea. I am reading everyday about the things.  Can there be redundancies in the files?. how to identify them and remove them? because these files were written back in 97.

Answer (score 0):

[MAKAO](http://sailhome.cs.queensu.ca/~bram/makao/index.html) may possibly be of use to you.  It allows you to print a call graph of an executed make.